# Do we need Google Cloud Project for using Dialogflow v2 with Node?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I want to create a Chatbot using Dialogflow with Node.js and integrate it with the facebook messanger.
Dialogflow has recently launched version 2 of the API.
I just wanted to know whether it needs any Google cloud project or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You'll always need a GCP project to work with Dialogflow. You could however choose to get GCP's stackdriver facilities or not; but a project is a mandate.

Inside that project, you'll also need to have Dialogflow API's enabled.

Comment: It's saying enable Dialogflow API, but its not free. 
So I have to pay for sure if I ever chose to use V2?

Comment: GCP is not free. However it comes with $350 credits when you signup with a new account. You could use that and associate dialogflow with that project.

Comment: Do we get fake key of the project when we generate it without enabling billing?

Comment: Nopes. There is no fake key. Billing has to be enabled by giving an active credit card details. Worry not, even after using credits, google will not charge unless you consent to "upgrade"